# Perl: removing rest of the string after encountering a certain character

Tags: regex, perl, string

I am doing some clean up of data in a file. So, I read each line and check certain conditions and perform the appropriate operation in the file. One of the things I need to do is check for the occurrence of the character $ in the string. If found I need to delete the rest of the line including the $. Example, if the line is

```
abc$hello-goodbye
```

I need to get

```
abc
```

How do I do this in Perl with minimal code? Use regexp of some sort?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quickest is by an easy regular expression:

```
$string =~ s/\$.*//;
```

where

```
$string = 'abc$hello-goodbye';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use regex or a combination of [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) and [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).

This shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby,

```
>> "abc$def".split("$")[0]
=> "abc"
>>
```

Similarly, use the `split()` function from Perl to do this and get the first element. See `perldoc -f split` for more information